# How to echo style and script tags using php

Tags: javascript, php, tags, echo, stylesheet

hello i have a php page that is to output results in my html page using div through an ajax request medium,

i intend outpiting this results using listviews as my application targets mobile phones and tablets, so i am making use of the jquery mobile framework.

i have outputed my results successfully with this

```
   <?php header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *'); ?>
<?php

$users = ($_GET['users']);
$user = ($_GET['user']);



$con = mysqli_connect('localhost','whitech3_manage','famakin','whitech3_manage');
if (!$con) {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}


mysqli_select_db($con,"whitech3_manage");
$sql="SELECT * FROM data WHERE fromwhere = '".$users."' and towhere = '".$user."'";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
echo '<head>';
echo "<link rel='stylesheet' href='themes/transport.min.css' />";
echo "<link rel='stylesheet' href='themes/jquery.mobile.icons.min.css' />";
echo "<link rel='stylesheet' href='themes/jquery.mobile.structure-1.4.2.min.css' />";
echo "<script src='themes/jquery-1.10.2.min.js'></script>";
echo "<script src='themes/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.js'></script>";

echo '</head>';




while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
echo "<div data-role='collapsible' data-theme='b' data-content-theme='b'>";

    echo "<ul data-role='listview' data-filter='true'>";
       echo "<li><a href='#'>". $row['fromwhere'] . "</a></li>";
          echo "<li><a href='#'>". $row['towhere'] . "</a></li>";
             echo "<li><a href='#'>". $row['details'] . "</a></li>";
     echo "<li><a href='#'>". $row['time frame'] . "</a></li>";


 echo "</ul>";
echo "</div>";
}

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

but whenever my results are displayed they r not formatted properly to look like a listview, hence i knw i am supposed to load my style sheets and javascript tags to make sure the listview is displayed properly.

i have tried and tried to echo the links to my stylesheets and js using echo statements, but it dosent seem to make my listview show up properly.

this is what i have tried

```
echo '<head>';
echo "<link rel='stylesheet' href='themes/transport.min.css' />";
echo "<link rel='stylesheet' href='themes/jquery.mobile.icons.min.css' />";
echo "<link rel='stylesheet' href='themes/jquery.mobile.structure-1.4.2.min.css' />";
echo "<script src='themes/jquery-1.10.2.min.js'></script>";
echo "<script src='themes/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.js'></script>";

echo '</head>';

function showUser() {
    if (showUser == "") {
        document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = "";

        return;
    } else { 
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else {
            // code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
        }
        var usersvalue=encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById("users").value)
var uservalue=encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById("user").value)
        xmlhttp.open("GET","http://whitechapelandpartners.com/getuserwrong.php?users="+usersvalue+"&user="+uservalue, true);


        xmlhttp.send();

    }
}

<div id="txtHint"><b>Person info will be listed here.</b></div><br /><br /><br /><br />
    </div>
```

any suggestion please, by logic i was hoping the echo statement would work

Comment: Use absolute path for your css / javascript, if you are not sure, how to use relative links. And where do you load this `<head></head>` section?

Comment: I suggest you check the outputted HTML code in your browser, it is likely an issue with the loaded CSS itself (or 404).

Comment: Have you considered [heredoc](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) or just ending your while with `?>`and have the html as plain html?

Comment: jquery need be refreshed on this div, so you need to add something like this : echo'<script>$.mobile.collapsibleset.prototype.options.initSelector = ".mycollapsibleset";
    $.mobile.collapsibleset.prototype.options.iconpos = "right";
</script>';

Comment: add it to where please @mimouni

Comment: your error is not in this php code, but when you get the response from ajax, please update you post by adding the part of loading page, in your javascript.

Comment: ok i will update it nw

Comment: here is the part of your big problem : xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText; //after this line we need to add a code for refresh jquery.
            }
        } // I'll try to add an answer now.

Comment: so then ill add the code snippet u gave me in the first instance, can u be kind enough to edit my snippet, an d repost it with the right stuff @mimouni

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
function showUser() {
    if (showUser == "") {
        document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = "";

        return;
    } else { 
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else {
            // code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                var collapsible = xmlhttp.responseText;
                document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = $(collapsible).collapsible();

            }
        }
        var usersvalue=encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById("users").value)
var uservalue=encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById("user").value)
        xmlhttp.open("GET","http://whitechapelandpartners.com/getuserwrong.php?users="+usersvalue+"&user="+uservalue, true);


        xmlhttp.send();

    }
}

<div id="txtHint"><b>Person info will be listed here.</b></div><br /><br /><br /><br />
    </div>
```

I hope this works. :D

Comment: nope that didnt work, note i didnt echo my tags on this html page, it was echoed in my php file, i will update my question further

Comment: the part of echo is not necessary delete it completly from php. echo '<head>';
echo "<link rel='stylesheet' href='themes/transport.min.css' />";
echo "<link rel='stylesheet' href=....

Comment: add this : print_r($result);   before  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)); I need a valid user to get results. can u give me one.

Comment: I need a valid user to get results. and doing the test form this link page. can u give me one.

Comment: take a view of this : http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.3.2/examples/collapsibles/dynamic-collapsible.html#&ui-state=dialog

Answer (score 0):

Here is my suggestion

```
<?php header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *'); ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel='stylesheet' href='themes/transport.min.css' />
<link rel='stylesheet' href='themes/jquery.mobile.icons.min.css' />
<link rel='stylesheet' href='themes/jquery.mobile.structure-1.4.2.min.css' />
<script type="text/javascript" src='themes/jquery-1.10.2.min.js'></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src='themes/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.js'></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

function showUser(user) { // how do you call this? You need to pass it a user too
    if (user == "") {
        $("#txtHint").empty();
        return;
    } 
    var usersvalue=encodeURIComponent($"#users").val()),
        uservalue=encodeURIComponent($("#user").val());
    // assuming you are accessing the same origin
    $.get("/getuserwrong.php?users="+usersvalue+"&user="+uservalue,
      function(data) {
        $("#txtHint").html(data);
      }
    ); 
}

</script>
</head>
<body>
<?php
$users = ($_GET['users']);
$user = ($_GET['user']);
// I think you do not want to show your userID and password here on this site
$con = mysqli_connect('localhost','...','...','...'); 
if (!$con) {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}
mysqli_select_db($con,"whitech3_manage");
$sql="SELECT * FROM data WHERE fromwhere = '".$users."' and towhere = '".$user."'";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {  
  echo <<<EOT 
    <div data-role='collapsible' data-theme='b' data-content-theme='b'>
      <ul data-role='listview' data-filter='true'>
        <li><a href='#'>$row['fromwhere']</a></li>
        <li><a href='#'>$row['towhere']</a></li>
        <li><a href='#'>$row['details']</a></li>
        <li><a href='#'>$row['time frame']</a></li>
      </ul>
   </div>
EOT;   
}
mysqli_close($con);
?>

<div id="txtHint"><b>Person info will be listed here.</b></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please note your have to access the same origin or use CORS - also I do not see a call to showUser and a parameter sent to it

Comment: my only problem with this is, the html file is supposed to be making an ajax request, because my intent is to be used in a mobile app using phonegap. so the php in my html wont work

Comment: Then you are confusing us with the PHP you have now.